# Perl Graph showing points too close to axis

Tags: perl, graph, gd

I am using the PERL GD::Graph module to make a GUI where a graph is made accepting values from the user. However, the data-points are just bunching up on the X-axis. This is the code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
# Change above line to point to your perl binary

use CGI ':standard';
use GD::Graph::points;
use GD::Graph::colour;
use strict;

# Both the arrays should same number of entries.

print "Please enter the number of data-values you have\n";
my $i = <STDIN>;
print "Please enter the gel eletrophoresis values and press enter after each value\n";
my @values;
for ( 1 .. $i ) {
    my $num = <STDIN>;
    chomp $num;
    push @values, $num;
}

my @data = ( [ 0 .. 450 ], [@values] );

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::points->new( 1000, 1000 );
$mygraph->set(
    title           => 'Gel Electrophoresis',
    transparent     => 0,
    bgclr           => 'white',
    dclrs           => [qw(black)],
    #y_tick_number   => 1,                       
    #x_tick_number   => 1,                       
    #no_axes         => 0,                       
    markers         => [9],
    marker_size     => 20,
    accent_treshold => 50,
    #values_vertical => 1,                       
) or warn $mygraph->error;

my $myimage = $mygraph->plot( \@data ) or die $mygraph->error;

print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
#print $myimage->png;

open IMG, '>file.png';
print IMG $myimage->png;
close IMG;
```

and this is the graph that I am getting.

[image]

As seen on the graph image, what change do I make in the code so that the plot points do not stay on the x-axis and stay on the graph. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to program.

Comment: I did not get the problem. Can you pls update your question and explain it in more detail.

Comment: And maybe you should start with static values in @data to see whats going on.

Comment: @smartmeta get it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like a scaling problem. You've got...

```
my @data = ( [ 0 .. 450 ], [@values] );
```

That `450` range value should probably be calculated to be just a tad higher that your highest "gel eletrophoresis" value. Use that same calculated value and add...

```
    y_max_value     => $calculated,
```

...to your...

```
$mygraph->set(...);
```

command.